# Alarm manager local notification - how to open a specific page when open notification?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have used alarm manager where user set date and time and he will get local notification on that date/time. The problem I am facing is, that I don't know how to navigate to specific a page when I open notification. Here is my **xamarin.android** code. I am using xamarin forms.

```
 public class LocalNotificationService : ILocalNotificationService
    {
        int _notificationIconId { get; set; }
        readonly DateTime _jan1st1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        internal string _randomNumber;

        public void LocalNotification(string title, string body, int id, DateTime notifyTime)
        {

            //long repeateDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
            long repeateForMinute = 60000;
            long totalMilliSeconds = (long)(notifyTime.ToUniversalTime() - _jan1st1970).TotalMilliseconds;
            if (totalMilliSeconds < JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis())
            {
                totalMilliSeconds = totalMilliSeconds + repeateForMinute;
            }

            var intent = CreateIntent(id);
            var localNotification = new ContactDetail();
            localNotification.Title = title;
            localNotification.Body = body;
            localNotification.Id = id;
            localNotification.TimeSchedule = notifyTime.ToString();

            if (_notificationIconId != 0)
            {
                localNotification.IconId = _notificationIconId;
            }
            else
            {
                localNotification.IconId = Resource.Drawable.af;
            }

            var serializedNotification = SerializeNotification(localNotification);
            intent.PutExtra(ScheduledAlarmHandler.LocalNotificationKey, serializedNotification);

            Random generator = new Random();
            _randomNumber = generator.Next(100000, 999999).ToString("D6");

            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, Convert.ToInt32(_randomNumber), intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
            var alarmManager = GetAlarmManager();
            alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, totalMilliSeconds, repeateForMinute, pendingIntent);
        }

        public void Cancel(int id)
        {

            var intent = CreateIntent(id);
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, Convert.ToInt32(_randomNumber), intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
            var alarmManager = GetAlarmManager();
            alarmManager.Cancel(pendingIntent);
            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Application.Context);
            notificationManager.CancelAll();
            notificationManager.Cancel(id);
        }

        public static Intent GetLauncherActivity()
        {

            var packageName = Application.Context.PackageName;
            return Application.Context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        }


        private Intent CreateIntent(int id)
        {

            return new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(ScheduledAlarmHandler))
                .SetAction("LocalNotifierIntent" + id);
        }

        private AlarmManager GetAlarmManager()
        {

            var alarmManager = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;
            return alarmManager;
        }

        private string SerializeNotification(ContactDetail notification)
        {

            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(notification.GetType());

            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, notification);
                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Label = "Local Notifications Broadcast Receiver")]
    public class ScheduledAlarmHandler : BroadcastReceiver
    {

        public const string LocalNotificationKey = "LocalNotification";

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            var extra = intent.GetStringExtra(LocalNotificationKey);
            var notification = DeserializeNotification(extra);
            //Generating notification
            var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.Context)
                .SetContentTitle(notification.Title)
                .SetContentText(notification.Body)
                .SetSmallIcon(notification.IconId)
                .SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Ringtone))
                .SetAutoCancel(true);

            var resultIntent = LocalNotificationService.GetLauncherActivity();
            resultIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
            var stackBuilder = Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder.Create(Application.Context);
            stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);

            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNumber = random.Next(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

            var resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(randomNumber, (int)PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
            builder.SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            // Sending notification
            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Application.Context);
            notificationManager.Notify(randomNumber, builder.Build());
        }

        private ContactDetail DeserializeNotification(string notificationString)
        {

            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ContactDetail));
            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(notificationString))
            {
                var notification = (ContactDetail)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
                return notification;
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my viewmodel code

```
 public class LocalNotificationPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        Command _saveCommand;
        public Command SaveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _saveCommand;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _saveCommand, value);
            }
        }

        bool _notificationONOFF;
        public bool NotificationONOFF
        {
            get
            {
                return _notificationONOFF;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _notificationONOFF, value);
                Switch_Toggled();
            }
        }

        void Switch_Toggled()
        {

            if (NotificationONOFF == false)
            {

                MessageText = string.Empty;
                SelectedTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
                SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
                DependencyService.Get<ILocalNotificationService>().Cancel(0);
            }
        }

        DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.Today;
        public DateTime SelectedDate
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedDate;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedDate, value);
            }
        }

        TimeSpan _selectedTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        public TimeSpan SelectedTime
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedTime;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedTime, value);
            }
        }

        string _messageText;
        public string MessageText
        {
            get
            {
                return _messageText;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _messageText, value);
            }
        }

        public LocalNotificationPageViewModel()
        {
            SaveCommand = new Command(() => SaveLocalNotification());
        }

        void SaveLocalNotification()
        {

            if (NotificationONOFF == true)
            {

                var date = (SelectedDate.Date.Month.ToString("00") + "-" + SelectedDate.Date.Day.ToString("00") + "-" + SelectedDate.Date.Year.ToString());

                var time = Convert.ToDateTime(SelectedTime.ToString()).ToString("HH:mm");

                var dateTime = date + " " + time;

                var selectedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MessageText))
                {

                    DependencyService.Get<ILocalNotificationService>().Cancel(0);
                    DependencyService.Get<ILocalNotificationService>().LocalNotification("Local Notification", MessageText, 0, selectedDateTime);
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("LocalNotificationDemo", "Notification details saved successfully ", "Ok");

                }
                else
                {
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("LocalNotificationDemo", "Please enter meassage", "OK");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("LocalNotificationDemo", "Please switch on notification", "OK");
            }
        }

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
           [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "",
           Action onChanged = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
                return false;
            backingStore = value;
            onChanged?.Invoke();
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed == null)
                return;
            changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Before this I have used push notification with firebase and I could easily open notification and navigate to specific that I want, but I don't know how to do with alarm manager notification.

Comment: could it work ?

Comment: yes man its works thanks a lot there is another issue if you could help

Comment: you could give me the link,i would check it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57979892/alarm-manager-local-notification-how-to-cancel-specific-notification

Comment: i have sent you link

Comment: yes, i see it ,let's talk [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199599/notification)

Comment: ok i text u there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

set **LaunchMode.SingleTop** to your **MainActiviy** :

```
[Activity(LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
public class MainActivity:FormsAppCompatActivity
```

add the **OnNewIntent** method in MainActiviy :

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
  {
    base.OnNewIntent(intent);
    NavigateTo(intent);
  }
```

in the **NavigateTo** method,you can determine if it is your notification by `intent.Action` or `intent.HasExtra`:

```
void NavigateTo(Intent intent)
{
  //the action and extra you could set in your resultIntent 
  if (intent.Action == "XXXX" && intent.HasExtra("XXXX"))
  {

     Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page());
  }
}
```

and you also could use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) in **NavigateTo** method to navigate a new page.

Comment: @waqaswaqas you could put the id as extra in resultIntent,like `resultIntent.PutExtra("XXX",id)`,then get the value in `NavigateTo` method by `intent.Extras.GetString("XXX")`,make the id as a parameter,like `new Page(id)`

Comment: can you tell me what is intent.Action == "XXXX"? what is xxxx what i have to write here?

Comment: @waqaswaqas this you could define by yourself like a flag which you could check if the intent is you need,ofcourse you could delete it and only use intent.HasExtra