# alarm manager local notification - how to cancel specific notification?

Tags: xamarin.forms

i am scheduling my customer through alarm manager to get notification on time that i set. Now everything is working fine i get local notification, but i am not able to cancel that specific notification its keep coming after every minute.

here is my viewmodel code PCL
for cancel :

```
void Switch_Toggled()
        {

            if (NotificationONOFF == false)
            {

                MessageText = string.Empty;
                SelectedTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
                SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
                DependencyService.Get<ILocalNotificationService>().Cancel(Convert.ToInt32(Settings.Customerid));
            }
        }
```

for save alarm

```
DependencyService.Get<ILocalNotificationService>().LocalNotification("Local Notification", MessageText, Convert.ToInt32(Settings.Customerid) , selectedDateTime);
```

code in xamarin.android
for canel:

```
public void Cancel(int id)
        {

            var intent = CreateIntent(id);
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, Convert.ToInt32(_randomNumber), intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
            var alarmManager = GetAlarmManager();
            alarmManager.Cancel(pendingIntent);
            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Application.Context);
            notificationManager.CancelAll();
            notificationManager.Cancel(id);
        }
```

i am sending customer id to cancel but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you have xamarin.forms sample, sending Local Notification With A Repeat Interval using Alarm Manager, like this sample:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-send-local-notification-with-repeat-interval-in-xamarin-forms/

There are two solution, but I don't know what you are.

Solution 1:

When you run project and set one alarm Manager to send local notification with a repeat interval, this app is background now.

When time is up, you go into this background app, you find switch is unselect, but alarm still exist. So you want to cancel this alarm when you go into this app, am I right?

If yes, I suggest you can call Switch_Toggled() event in LocalNotificationPageViewModel constructor.

```
public LocalNotificationPageViewModel(){
        SaveCommand = new Command(() => SaveLocalNotification());
        Switch_Toggled();
    }
```

Solution 2:

If you run project and set one alarm Manager to send local notification with a repeat interval, and this app still active, now time is up, you can unselect switch to cancel this alarm, it works fine.