# How to navigate to other pages on push notification tap without relauching app in Xamarin?

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to navigate to a new page when tapping on the push notification. I do not want to relaunch the page. Which means, when my application is already in the foreground, I just want to navigate to a new page(I need the back icon in the navigation bar). However, currently am able to only load the application which clears my existing navigation stack and reloads the application.

Below is my code in the FirebaseMessagingService class.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        var push = new Intent(this, typeof(PushActivity));
        push.PutExtra("NotificationId", DateTime.Now.ToString());
        push.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);

        var fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, push, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        var seed = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), @"\d+").Value);
        int id = new Random(seed).Next(000000000, 999999999);
        notification.SetContentIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent)
            .SetContentTitle(message.GetNotification().Title)
            .SetContentText(message.GetNotification().Body);
        manager.Notify(id, notification.Build());
    }
}
```

Below is my MainActivity code.

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);

        string NotificationId = Intent.GetStringExtra("NotificationId");
        if (NotificationId == null)
            LoadApplication(new App(false));
        else
            LoadApplication(new App(true));
    }
}
```

Below is my App.cs file code.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private bool _isNotified;
    public App(bool isNotified)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._isNotified = isNotified;
        if (_isNotified)
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ReceiveNotification());
        else
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        this._isNotified = false;
    }

    public static void NavigateToReceiveNotificationPage()
    {
        App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ReceiveNotification());
    } 
}
```

Note: I have already achieved this requirement in the iOS by calling the NavigateToReceiveNotificationPage method from the renderer. Whereas in Android since the main activity itself reloads am not sure how to achieve this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could set your MainActivity **LaunchMode** to **SingleTop**,then handle it in **OnNewIntent** method,

```
[Activity(Label = "App18", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize,LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop )]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    ...
  
    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        string NotificationId = intent.Extras.GetString("NotificationId");
        //do something you want to do (according to your own needs,you also could use MessagingCenter to do what you want in forms page)
        Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page());
    }

   ...
}
```

[MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)

you could refer to [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57967968/10768653)

**Update**:

put the data to Intent :

```
var push = new Intent(this, typeof(PushActivity));
var bundleForPush = new Bundle();
bundleForPush.PutString("NotificationId", DateTime.Now.ToString());
push.PutExtras(bundleForPush);
```

Comment: Hi @Leo,
Thanks a lot it works. But having a small issue. Am doing this but could not get this working. 

//I have below code while receiving notifications. 
var push = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                push.PutExtra("NotificationId", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                push.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);

//In the OnNewIntent
string notificationId = Intent.GetStringExtra("NotificationId");
            if (notificationId != null)
                Do work();

However, the above code is not working. notificationId is coming as null. Do you know why?

Comment: @Harikrishnanh try to add the value into a `Bundle`,then put into intent and get it in `OnNewIntent` like above

Comment: Instead of "Intent.GetStringExtra("NotificationId")", using "intent.Extras.GetString("NotificationId")" did the trick. Thanks a lot. I'll mark it as answer.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Plugin.FirebasePushNotification and you can hook this in App.xaml.cs:

```
CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += async (s, p) =>{};
```

Comment: Thanks @sermet. However, am not looking for any plugin. Am looking for an actual solution since I have done all by myself without using any plugin. 
But I'll make use of this in my next project for sure. Thanks for it.

Comment: @sermet where do we initialize the OnNotificationOpened handler?

Comment: @AsımGündüz you can assign it in app.xaml.cs onstart method.